# Export a postgis table to geopackage using the DB database manager in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage, postgis-2.0

I am working in QGIS through the DB Manager by running some spatial queries. After I create new tables with the queries I need to export the tables as new geopackages. I've tried using the Export to Vector file inside the DB Manager but I get the following error message:

> Error 2 Creation of data source failed (OGR error:
> sqlite3_open(/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xx/new_geopackage_layer.gpkg)failed:
> unable to open database file)

I've read a couple of posts and they said I needed to create an empty geopackage first and then export the table and save it inside the geopackage but that did not work either. When I try to save inside an existing geopackage I get an error saying:

> "geopackage.gpkg already exists. Do you want to replace it? A file or
> folder with the same name already exists in the folder xxx Replacing
> it will overwrite its current contents."

If I choose to overwrite then I get a second error message saying:

> " Error 1 Unable to create the datasource.
> /Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/new_geopackage.gpkg exists
> and overwrite flag is false."

All I want is to be able to run spatial queries inside QGIS and be able to export the tables created with the queries as geopackages.

It seems that as of now I won't be able to do this from inside QGIS but instead will need to use ogr2ogr command to export to any file type.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the layer and then selecting Export > Save Features As? GeoPackage is one of the export options (at least in version 3.24)

Comment: @RudyStricklan yes, I tried and your solution worked with a table with only one geometry. The problem might be coming from my table having two geometry columns in PostGIS. One is called geom and the other one is called geom_single. I am able to vizualise the table in QGIS but if I want to make a copy of the same table and save as a geopackage, then I cannot do it.

Comment: From the GPKG standard `Requirement 30 A feature table SHALL have only one geometry column.`